# Find Id's with start/end date range coverage caps greater than 20 days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I need to find all Id's that have 20 or more days outside of date ranges, between the first StartDate and last EndDate.

One Id has multiple start dates and end dates. In the following example, Id 1 has two gaps less than 20 days each. It should be considered as one range from 10/01/2012 to 10/30/2014 without any gap.

```
1   10/01/2012  02/01/2013
1   01/01/2013  01/31/2013
1   02/10/2013  03/31/2013
1   04/15/2013  10/30/2014
```

Id 2 has a gap more than 20 days between end date 01/30/2013 and start date 05/01/2013, therefore it has to be captured by the query.

```
2   01/01/2013  01/30/2013
2   05/01/2013  06/30/2014
2   07/01/2013  02/01/2014
```

Id 3 should be considered as one range from 01/01/2012 to 06/01/2014 without any gap. The gap  between end date 02/28/2013 and start date 07/01/2013 should be ignored because range from 01/01/2012 to 01/01/2014 covers the gap.

```
3   01/01/2012  01/01/2014
3   01/01/2013  02/28/2013
3   07/01/2013  06/01/2014
```

A cursor can do it but it works extremely slow and is not acceptable.

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27e3f/2/0

Comment: Can you write out what you want your output to look like?

Comment: I need to select Id 2 only because there is uncovered gap > 20 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your fiddle schema, try this:

```
;WITH naivegaps AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id, startdate, MAX(dr1.enddate)) AS rn,
    dr1.Id, dr1.startdate, MAX(dr1.enddate) as enddate    
  FROM dateranges dr1
  GROUP BY dr1.Id, dr1.startdate
)
SELECT n1.id, n1.enddate as gap_start, n2.startdate AS gap_end, 
  datediff(dd, n1.enddate, n2.startdate) as gap_width, n3.*
FROM naivegaps n1
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 nx.id, nx.startdate
    FROM naivegaps nx
    WHERE n1.id = nx.id AND nx.rn > n1.rn
    ORDER BY nx.startdate
  ) n2
  OUTER APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 nx.id, nx.enddate
    FROM naivegaps nx
    WHERE n1.id = nx.id AND nx.rn < n1.rn
    ORDER BY nx.enddate DESC
  ) n3
WHERE datediff(dd, n1.enddate, n2.startdate) >= 20 AND (n3.enddate <= n1.enddate OR n3.enddate IS NULL)
```

The CTE at the top orders everything appropriately for the following checks, and adds a row number to facilitate ordering checks.  The `CROSS APPLY` finds all gaps between the end of a sequence and the following beginning.  The `OUTER APPLY` checks for ranges that completely surround the gap in question (that wouldn't have been sorted appropriately in the `CROSS APPLY`)

EDIT:  I compared the execution plan of this solution against the recursive CTE solution provided by Joe Farrell.  They're significantly different plans, but the estimated efficiency is very close (mine is slightly better, about 4%).  This may or may not translate to real-world performance on a large data set; I encourage you to test both approaches and use the one that works best in your scenario.

Comment: Thank you. It runs 4 times faster than cursor.

Comment: Can you check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5bb1a/1/0 please? It does not select id 4 with gap from 2013-12-31 to 2014-03-01

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that doesn't use a cursor. I don't know how fast it will be on a large data set, so hopefully you can test it against your cursor-based approach and let me know how it holds up. A more detailed explanation of what's going on follows the code.

```
-- Get a list of all dates on which coverage starts or stops.
with [EventsCTE] as
(
    select [id], [startdate] as [date], 1 as [change] from dateranges
    union all
    select [id], [enddate] as [date], -1 as [change] from dateranges
),

-- Give each event a sequence number (by date) within its id.
[SequencedEventsCTE] as
(
    select row_number() over (partition by [id] order by [date]) as [seq], *
    from [EventsCTE]
),

-- Use the sequence number to construct a running total of the number of active
-- date ranges at each point in time.
[RunningTotalsCTE] as
(
    -- Base case: Get the first event for each id.
    select *, [change] as [rangesActive] 
    from [SequencedEventsCTE] where [seq] = 1

    union all

    -- Recursive case: build a running total for subsequent events.
    select [this].*, [this].[change] + [prev].[rangesActive] as [rangesActive]
    from [SequencedEventsCTE] [this]
        inner join [RunningTotalsCTE] [prev] on
            [this].[Id] = [prev].[Id] and
            [this].[seq] = [prev].[seq] + 1
),

-- Join each event to its successor and look for dates on which no range was 
-- active. This gives us a list of gaps and their sizes.
[GapsCTE] as
(
    select [gapStart].[Id], 
        datediff(day, [gapStart].[date], [gapEnd].[date]) as [GapSize]
    from [RunningTotalsCTE] [gapStart]
        inner join [RunningTotalsCTE] [gapEnd] on
            [gapStart].[Id] = [gapEnd].[Id] and
            [gapStart].[seq] = [gapEnd].[seq] - 1 and
            [gapStart].[rangesActive] = 0
)

-- Get the ids having gaps of 20 days or more.
select distinct [id] from [GapsCTE] where [GapSize] >= 20;
```

First, in `EventsCTE`, I split each of the rows from your original table into two "events", one denoting that a date range has begun (these records have `change = 1`), and one denoting that a date range has ended (`change = -1`). Starting with this seemed necessary because of the fact that you have overlapping ranges; I can't identify gaps by just comparing one record in the original table to the record that follows it.

`SequencedEventsCTE` takes this expanded data set and adds a new column, `seq`, which gives the relative sequence of a particular event within each `id`. This allow me to easily match each event to the event that comes immediately before it in my next step.

`RunningTotalsCTE` has the trick that makes this whole thing work: for each event, it computes a running total of the `change` values within each `id`. This running total, `rangesActive`, should therefore give the number of date ranges were active as of each event date. This allows me to account for overlapping date ranges. For instance, if you select all of the records from `RunningTotalsCTE` where `id = 3`, you get the following:

```
seq  id  date                     change  rangesActive
1    3   2012-01-01 00:00:00.000  1       1
2    3   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000  1       2
3    3   2013-02-28 00:00:00.000  -1      1
4    3   2013-07-01 00:00:00.000  1       2
5    3   2014-01-01 00:00:00.000  -1      1
6    3   2014-06-01 00:00:00.000  -1      0
```

Finally, `GapsCTE` identifies all of the gaps by looking for records where `rangesActive = 0`, excluding the last event within each `id`. The size of the gap is the difference between such a record's event date and the event date of the record that follows it. The last step is to simply select the unique `id`s from this final CTE where there's a gap size of 20 days or more.

I think this will do what you want, though as I said, I'm not sure how it will perform against a very large data set. Please comment if you have any specific questions about how this works.

Comment: The recursive CTE is dangerous here.  I tried testing this against a moderate dataset (600 rows or so) and got "Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."

Comment: Good point. The recursion depth depends on the number of date ranges per `id`, so it may or may not be a problem depending on what the data set looks like, but I've tested it with a large data set now that I have a bit more time, and the performance seems to scale very poorly. Your solution looks a lot better.

Comment: Replacing [SequencedEventsCTE] with temp table made a huge difference. It runs in seconds now. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I reread your post and edited this response a bit, this should be a bit closer to what you actually want:

You can do this with min, max, group by, and date diff.

```
Select T.Id, T.MinStartDate, T.MaxEndDate
FROM DateTable D
JOIN(SELECT Id, MIN(StartDate) AS  MinStartDate, MAX(EndDate) AS MaxEndDate, DATEDIFF(day, 
MIN(StartDate), MAX(EndDate)) AS Duration
FROM DateTable
GROUP BY Id) AS T ON T.id = D.id AND T.Duration > 20
```

For more info about datediff: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: It does not do any help.

Comment: I need to select Id 2 only because there is uncovered gap > 20 days.